# Why do some of my images placed in a Vue template disappear when content in filtered?

Tags: vue.js, drupal, filtering

I've been put in charge of a Drupal website that has some content that is placed through a complex set of Vue files. I've never used Vue so I need some help with a critical problem we're facing.

I have a news section on the site that users can filter from a dropdown (by choosing a topic from the menu). This works fine. However, whenever you bring back a previously filtered news story, the featured image fails to load. The Vue template brings back the default image. But this only happens for SOME of the images.

As I mentioned, the Vue.js file is complex - it imports nearly a dozen other files that control other features of the site. This is the code from the the most applicable file:

```
export default {
    props: {
        url: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        tag: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
        },
        eyebrow: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        image: {
            type: Object,
            required: false,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        imageUrl() {
            return this.image && this.image.url ? this.image.url : '/themes/my-theme/images/no-image.jpg';
        }
    },
    template: `
        <a :href="url" class="news-card">
            <span class="news-card__image">
                <img :src="imageUrl" :alt="image.alt">
            </span>
            <span class="news-card__text">
                <span class="news-card__tag" v-if="tag" v-html="tag">
                </span>
                <p class="news-card__eyebrow" v-if="eyebrow">
                    {{ eyebrow }}
                </p>
                <h2 class="news-card__title">
                    {{ title }}
                </h2>
            </span>
        </a>
    `
};
```

I would post more, but I don't know what else is needed to diagnose a Vue issue. Sorry, I'm brand new to Vue and it's very confusing!

UPDATE
I've added the view.js code below:

```
import Vue from '@vue';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import ListingGrid from '/components/listing-grid';
import ListingNav from '/components/listing-nav';
import ProgramCard from '/components/program-card';
import ListingCard from '/components/listing-card';
import NewsCard from '/components/news-card';
import ListingFilters from '/components/listing-filters';
import ListingLoader from '/components/listing-loader';
import ListingStickyNav from '/components/listing-sticky-nav';
import TabSelect from '/components/tab-select';
import ajaxStore from './store/ajax';
import staticStore from './store/static';

export default (id) => {
    new Vue({
        el: `#${id}`,
        components: {
            ListingFilters,
            ListingGrid,
            ListingNav,
            ProgramCard,
            ListingCard,
            NewsCard,
            ListingLoader,
            ListingStickyNav,
            TabSelect,
        },
        data: {
            lazy: true
        },
        store: id === 'listing-static' ? staticStore : ajaxStore,
        computed: mapState({
            grid() {
                return this.$store.getters.filteredGrid;
            },
            filters: state => state.filters,
            tabs: state => state.tabs,
            loading: state => state.loading,
            showLoader: state => state.infiniteLoading,
            cardType: state => state.cardType
        }),
        image: {
            type: Object,
            default: function () {
                return {
                    url: '/themes/my-theme/images/no-image.jpg',
                    alt: 'Default No Image Alt Text'
                }
            },
        },
        template: `
            <main class="view__content v-listing vue-loaded" id="${id}">
                <listing-sticky-nav>
                    <template slot="tab-content">
                        <tab-select
                            :tabs="tabs"
                            v-if="tabs.items"
                        >
                        </tab-select>
                    </template>
                    <template slot="panel">
                        <listing-filters
                            :filters="filters"
                            additional-classes="mobile"
                        >
                        </listing-filters>
                    </template>
                </listing-sticky-nav>
                <listing-filters
                    :filters="filters"
                >
                </listing-filters>
                <listing-grid
                    :has-results="grid.length > 0"
                    :loading="loading"
                    :lazy="lazy">
                    <listing-nav
                        v-if="tabs"
                        :tabs="tabs"
                        slot="nav"
                    >
                    </listing-nav>
                    <template slot="grid">
                        <component
                            :is="cardType"
                            v-bind="item"
                            v-for="item, index in grid"
                            :key="index">
                        </component>
                    </template>
                    <template slot="empty">
                        No results found.
                    </template>
                </listing-grid>
                <span class="v-listing-footer" v-if="showLoader">
                    <listing-loader></listing-loader>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">loading</span>
                </span>
            </main>
        `
    });
}
```

Comment: I would suggest getting the vue devtools browser extension for chrome or firefox and then you can inspect what the `imageUrl` computed property is resolving to for the images that aren't showing correctly.

Comment: [so] is a place where you ask technical questions. If your question is useful to others with a similar technical challenge, it is generally up-voted. Insights of employment status, whether or not you currently find a particular technology confusing and other personal context are more often than not irrelevant, considered off-topic and should be replaced by the results of any documentation effort and/or any coding attempt. Statistically, questions containing a *runnable* [mcve] demonstrating the issue are well received and answered at a higher rate.

Comment: In short, you are quite vague about the problem (from a technical perspective) and you don't provide enough detail so that it could be reproduced. Therefore your question is currently un-answerable without guessing. To improve your chances at getting a useful answer, please read and apply [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with the comments above that there are many lacking elements, I am a huge proponent of VueJS and I would like to help if possible.

First glaring issue I see is that the property `image` is not required. The computed property `imageUrl()` is defensive in that it will return a default value of `'/themes/my-theme/images/no-image.jpg'` if the property `image` is omitted.

However in your template code in the `<img />` you are referencing the object key of 'alt' from the `image` object which may or may not be present.

I would highly recommend adding a computed property of:

```
imageAlt() {
    return this.image && this.image.alt ? this.image.alt : 'Default No Image Alt Text';
}
```

Then in your template update the image tag as follows:

```
<img :src="imageUrl" :alt="imageAlt">
```

This will harden your code ensuring that error cannot happen. You may want to update the default Alt Text as it was provided for example purposes only.

If this does not work in resolving the issue please comment with the following information for additional assistance.

1. Are there any JS errors in the console?
2. Did you download the [Vue Devtools extension](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools)?
3. If so what is the computed properties value for imageUrl when working and after you experience this issue?

Update. As an alternative approach (and I prefer this) you could also remove all computed properties and provided a default `image` object. This would require no observers and looks like this:

```
image: {
    type: Object,
    default: function () {
        return {
            url: '/themes/my-theme/images/no-image.jpg',
            alt: 'Default No Image Alt Text'
        }
    },
}
```

Your image tag would then look like this:

```
<img :src="image.url" :alt="image.alt">
```

For more info visit: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. Neither option fixed the issue. The second (your preferred) option caused the src of the <img> to be set to {{ unknown }} on the broken images.

I only have one Vue-related error in the console: "You are running Vue in development mode."

I installed the DevTools and the imageUrl is set appropriately on the initial page load. Once the filtering fails and the image disappears, the imageUrl is set to " ".

Comment: Specifically, the props section of DevTools has imageUrl set to " "

The computed section prints out the src of the no-image.jpg file

Comment: Hi Tim - any chance you can offer more help? Thanks! @TimWickstrom.com

Comment: Specifically, the props section of DevTools has imageUrl this should NOT be a prop. Are you using the first or second option I proposed?  Can you update with the code from the parent component that passes data to this component?

Comment: I'm using the second piece of code you provided. I had placed it in the props (in place of the image: line that's in my original code. I will update the parent component when I get to work tomorrow. I'll post after I update it.

Comment: Sounds good, I have a very busy morning but will check back. If you can isolate the code in a JS Fiddle that would be helpful as well.

Comment: I added your suggested edits in (what I think... but doubt) the correct way but the problem persists. I've updated the original post to include the view.js file that includes the previous code.

Comment: OK, so I tried to create a CodePen for this but it won't work. I realized that the gulp file used in the dev files was outputting all of the individual Vue files to one big view.js file. I am trying to use that in the CodePen but it makes all of the content disappear. You can see the test CodePen here: https://codepen.io/sherman/pen/KYqEOr

Comment: Sorry for all of the updates but I think I have the problem narrowed down.

return this.image && this.image.url ? this.image.url : '/themes/my-theme/images/no-image.jpg';

I need to know where the 'image' item is set. I can't figure out where that variable is being established and set to the correct src. Do you have any idea where it might be? Is it possible that it's set outside the Vue files and in the Drupal template pages?

Comment: Sorry for all of the updates. The "image" variable used in my code is being set by the Drupal template files. Users have two ways they can add images. If they upload them one way, it works. The other way causes this issue.

On page load, the Vue template gets the correct version every time. However, whenever i use the filters, it only tries to fetch one of the two possible types. This causes the error.

I need to figure out how to get Vue and the template file to always grab the correct image type.

Comment: Too many variable to properly debug here. If you wanted to set up a private repo or invite me to your current repo I could take a look. send me a private message to connect further on this. Best, Tim